# Getting a blank white screen after i deploy my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

Been trying to deploy my multi page react app with react router. After i deployed and published to github pages, i am still getting a fully blank white screen upon entering my app.  i am at a complete loss here and could use some help!

here is what i am gettting in the console once i go to the web url it is deployed on

```
(index):1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/19496/my-portfolio/src/App.css
main.5c8c6e6f.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
2.59462e7f.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
2.cd1c2086.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.900f82dd.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
2.59462e7f.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.900f82dd.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
(index):1 Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Users/19496/my-portfolio/src/App.css
2.cd1c2086.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.5c8c6e6f.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

here is my index.js, which i changed from Router to HashRouther

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.css';
import 'react-mdl/extra/material.js';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<HashRouter>
<App />
</HashRouter>
, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

My app.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Layout, Header, Navigation, Drawer, Content, Button, } from 'react-mdl';
import Main from './components/main';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="demo-big-content">
    <Layout>
        <Header className="header-color" title={<Link style={{textDecoration: 'none', color: 'white'}} to="/">MyPortfolio</Link>} scroll>
            <Navigation>
                <Link to="/resume">Resume</Link>
                <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
                <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </Navigation>
        </Header>

        <Drawer title={<Link style={{textDecoration: 'none', color: 'black'}} to="/">MyPortfolio</Link>}>
            <Navigation>
              <Link to="/resume">Resume</Link>
              <Link to="/projects">Projects</Link>
              <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
            </Navigation>
        </Drawer>
        <Content>
            <div className="page-content" />
            <Main/>
        </Content>
    </Layout>
</div>

    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

my package.json file

```
{
  "homepage":"https://Nickryan13/github.io/deploy-react",
  "name": "my-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-landing-page": "^2.0.2",
    "react-mdl": "^2.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

App.css

```
.header-color {
  background: #833ab4;  /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */

}

.landing-grid {
  background: #833ab4;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fcb045, #fd1d1d, #833ab4); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.projects-grid{
  display: flex;
}
.avatar-img{
  height: 185px;
  padding: 5em;
}
.banner-text{
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .8;
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.banner-text h1 {
  font-size: 66px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
.banner-text hr{
  border-top: 5px dotted white;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
.banner-text p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1.5em;

}
.social-links {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

.social-links i {
  color: white;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 8px;

}



.social-link i {
  color: red;
  font-size: 5em;
  padding: 8px;

}

.resume-right-col{
  background: #27221F;
  color:white;
  padding:2em;
}

.contact-body{
  margin: auto;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
.contact-grid{
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 80%;
  height: 550px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.contact-grid h2{
  font-family: Anton, sans-serif;
}
.contact-grid p{
  font-family: Oxygen, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.contact-grid hr{
  border-top: 5px dotted black;
  width: 50%;
  margin:auto;
}
.contact-list i{
  font-size: 66px;
  padding-right: 5rem;
}
```

Comment: Cold you add your App.css?

Comment: yes, i just added it to the post. thank you

Comment: Try to add this to your package.json: 
"build": {
    "directories": {
        "output": "release/"
    }
}

Comment: tried it and it didnt work

Comment: page still blank when i deploy it. app works just fine locally. could it be the errors in the console that are causing the page not to show up on the web?

Comment: Try first get rid of console errors, yes. Once there are none, let me know what’s happening.